# How can I get the actual parent folder when tilde(~) gives me the node_modules folder?

Tags: javascript, angular, sass

I'm running an app written in Angular 2.

In `angular.json` file I have:

```
        "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
          "includePaths": [
            "node_modules"
          ]
        },
```

and because of that I can, in `.scss` files, import things from `node_modules` this way:

```
@import "~@clr/ui/src/utils/dependencies.clarity";
```

, so use `~` as a root, which is `node_modules` here.

I would like to go to parent folder from `~`, but doing this like:

```
@import "~/../node_modules/@clr/ui/src/utils/dependencies.clarity";
```

is not working.

I know that I could simply add something more to `includePaths`, but is it possible to somehow go to parent of `~` in `import`?

Maybe I'm typing something wrong, but I tried few ways, and none were working...